# Pandas: Add and Preserve time component when input file has only date in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

### Scenario:

The input file which I read in Pandas has column with sparsely populated date in String/Object format.
I need to add time component, for ex.
2021-08-27 is my input in String format, and 2021-08-28 00:00:00 should by output in datetime64[ns] format

### My Trials:

```
df = pd.read_parquet("sample.parquet")
df.head()
```

| a | b | c | dttime_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2021-07-12 00:00:00 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | NaN |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | NaN |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2021-02-04 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 5 | 2 | NaN |

```
df["dttime_col"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dttime_col"])
df["dttime_col"]
Out[16]: 
0   2021-07-12
1          NaT
2          NaT
3   2021-02-04
4          NaT
5   2021-05-22
6          NaT
7   2021-10-06
8   2021-01-31
9          NaT
Name: dttime_col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But as you see here, there is not time component. I tried adding format as `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` but still the output is same. Further more, I tried adding Time component as default as a String type.

```
df["dttime_col"] = df["dttime_col"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00").replace('NaT', np.nan)
Out[17]: 
0    2021-07-12 00:00:00
1                    NaN
2                    NaN
3    2021-02-04 00:00:00
4                    NaN
5    2021-05-22 00:00:00
6                    NaN
7    2021-10-06 00:00:00
8    2021-01-31 00:00:00
9                    NaN
Name: dttime_col, dtype: object
```

Now this gives me time next to date, but in String/Object format. The moment I convert it back to datetime format, all the HH:MM:SS are removed.

```
df["dttime_col"].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") if not isinstance(x, float) else np.nan)
Out[24]: 
0   2021-07-12
1          NaT
2          NaT
3   2021-02-04
4          NaT
5   2021-05-22
6          NaT
7   2021-10-06
8   2021-01-31
9          NaT
Name: dttime_col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

It feels like going in circles all again.

### Output I expect:

```
0    2021-07-12 00:00:00
1                    NaN
2                    NaN
3    2021-02-04 00:00:00
4                    NaN
5    2021-05-22 00:00:00
6                    NaN
7    2021-10-06 00:00:00
8    2021-01-31 00:00:00
9                    NaN
Name: dttime_col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

### EDIT 1:

Providing output as asked by @mozway

```
df["dttime_col"].dt.second
Out[27]: 
0    0.0
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    0.0
4    NaN
5    0.0
6    NaN
7    0.0
8    0.0
9    NaN
Name: dttime_col, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Did you trying adding `format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` (and maybe `unit='s'`) to `pd.to_datetime`?

Comment: Can you provide the output of  `df["dttime_col"].dt.second` right after reading the file and right after converting to datetime? (one row only)

Comment: @Quixotic22 I tried adding the format into `to_datetime` but the output is still the same. I haven't tried with `unit='s'`.

Comment: your problem is just a display problem, because even if you don't see the time component, when the `dtype` fo the column is `datetime64[ns]`, you can still access the time with `dt.time` even if they are 00:00:00. Then using `strftime` to display the time works. So the question is why you need the time to display and keep the `datetime64[ns]` type, what is the use case? is it to write it back with this format to csv? to display on a screen to a user?

Comment: @mozway Sure, please check EDIT 1 section

Comment: @Ben.T Not csv per se, but in Parquet. But yes the intention is quite what you pointed. The time needs to be seen in the output file. Apparently, the File is accessed by Data Analyst and is also used to write it into Snowflake. Even Snowflake shows "invalid date" format in that column.

Comment: @Quixotic22 Just tried with `unit='s'`, returned `ValueError: non convertible value 2021-07-12 with the unit 's'`.

Comment: @T3J45 ok so your question is more about how to keep the time when writing datetime column `to_parquet`  :)

Comment: @Ben.T Ya, that boils it down. Any ideas there?

Comment: @T3J45 I don't know much about parquet, but from what I read, it seems tricky to keep datetime dtype. If the end goal is to load in snowflake, maybe use isoformat style that can probably be recognize when importing in snowflake. so `df["dttime_col"] = df["dttime_col"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` then export to_parquet.